# Excel Formula IF function with return blank if there is no Data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need on help on Excel formula for if function. 
I am working on transferring data from one file to another template and i would like to use the "=IF(B17="done","Completed","In-Process")" to identify if there is a word "Done" in the cell then it will populate as Completed or if there is date in the cell it should show "In-Process". I am success on this but when i move to #16-#22 if there is no data fill out for it. It still show as In-process. 
Is there anyway to include formula to tell excel that if there is no data it should leave the cell blank.
Note status in column B is exact automatic exact from another file. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks all, I got the idea. here is the new formula for cell #16 =IF(ISBLANK(B17)," ",IF(B17="done","completed","In-process"))                    Please let me know if there is a better way

Answer (score 1):

One way is to nest two if statements:

```
=IF(B17="","",IF(B17="done","Completed","In-Process"))
```

In English: If B17 is blank, return blank, else if B17 = "Done" return "Completed" else return "In-Progress"

Comment: Thanks 
cybernetic.nomad. However, there is a pop up "Inconsistent formula" when i am using your formula listed above.

Comment: [This error means that the formula in the cell doesn't match the pattern of the formulas nearby.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fix-an-inconsistent-formula-5dd940a1-4f87-44bd-91dd-bf45ed828f05).